# Canvas size confusion in 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm doing a 2D game and I'm new in unity.

How should I setup my Canvas for UI or Menu? I Mean what size they should be? Suppose If I add a Canvas with size of 1920x1080, what will happen when I build and run to a device with a resolution much less or higher than that?

Second question: If I force my game to open just Horizontally what will happen to those device which doesn't support changing Orientation?

regards

Comment: there are options on your canvas to resize...

Answer (score 0):

If you click on Canvas in your hierarchy, you can find a property "Canvas scaler" in the inspector. Change the "UI Scale Mode" to "Scale with Screen Size" and Set "Screen Match Mode" to 0.5